# Python3 SyntaxError while building a distribution file

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I am trying to create a distribution file in python33, but without any success.

I created a folder with nester name & put in python33 in C driver in windows 8.
This folder has 2 files. nester.py & setup.py

my setup.py has

```
from distutils.core import setup

    setup (

    name = 'nester';
    version = '1.0.0';
    py_modules = ['nester'];
    author = 'AMiSH13';

    )
```

Then I opened a CMD, aftar that I wrote

```
C:\python33\python.exe setup.py sdist
```

in this step, an error accured

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried this in Ubuntu also. I put my  files in nseter folder. After that
I opened a terminal with following commands

```
python3 setup.py sdist
```

in this case, linux can't open file 'setup.py' No such file or directory 
display.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Function arguments are separated by commas, not semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here:

1. Function arguments are separated by commas, not semicolons.  This is what is causing the `SyntaxError`.
2. Your indentation is bad and will raise an `IndentationError`.  Remember that Python takes indentation seriously since it uses it to determine what goes with what.

Your code should be like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='nester',
    version='1.0.0',
    py_modules=['nester'],
    author='AMiSH13'
)
```

Or alternatively, like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='nester', version='1.0.0', py_modules=['nester'], author='AMiSH13')
```

Comment: Thank you. I pasted your code, but it displayed syntaxError again.
File "<stdin>", Line 1
setup.py sdist
SyntaxError : invalid syntax

Comment: @AMiSH13 - Huh.  I tested both code snippets in Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 and I didn't get a `SytaxError`.  Did you copy it correctly?  If so, then I'm afraid I don't know why that happened.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you need to update.
1. update your setup.py

`from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='nester',
    version='1.0.0',
    py_modules=['nester'],
    author='AMiSH13',
)`

see the comma after AMiSH13

2. use command as 
   `C:\python33\python setup.py sdist`